# Post Api not return any response in nest js

Tags: postgresql, nestjs

I use nestjs and psql and I want upload files and save the url in the database . when I run the api , data save on db but it doesn’t return any response .
this is my service:

```
 async uploadFiles(files){
    if (!files) {
      throw new HttpException(
        {
          errorCode: UploadApplyOppErrorEnum.FileIsNotValid,
          message: UploadApplyOppMsgEnum.FileIsNotValid,
        },
        HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
      );
    }
    const filedata = OrderFilesData(files);
     return filedata.map(async(filePath) => {
      let orderFile = new OrderFile();
      orderFile.fileUrl = filePath.fileUrl;
      orderFile.type = filePath.fileType;
      try {
         let result = await this.orderFileRepository.save(orderFile);         
         return await result
      } catch (error) {
        throw new BadRequestException(error.detail);
      }
    });
  }
```

and this is my controller

```
  @UploadOrderFilesDec()
  @Post('upload')
  uploadFiles(@UploadedFiles() files){
     return this.ordersService.uploadFiles(files);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return an array of async methods without using `Promise.all()`, otherwise the promises haven't resolved yet. You can either use `return Promise.all(fileData.map(asyncFileMappingFunction))` or you can use a regular `for` loop and await over the results.